# Using .xib file as the custom camera overlayview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I created a CameraOverlayViewController with .xib file to implement a customized camera overlayView with. The overlayView is just a transparent background with a button to select photo from the photoLibrary and it loads successfully in the mainViewController with the following code:

```
CameraOverlayViewController* overlay = [[CameraOverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraOverlayViewController" bundle:nil];
cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView = overlay.view;
```

However, nothing happens when I pressed the button on the cameraOverlayView. No error messages, nothing. Does anyone know what's going on here? Below is my code in the CameraOverlayViewController file:

```
- (IBAction)select:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        [self presentViewController:picker
                           animated:YES completion:nil];

    }];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    NSLog(@"Just work alrdy!!!");
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
-(IBAction)select:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    [self presentViewController:picker
                       animated:YES completion:nil];  ////////check this is called??????

    }];
}
```